# How to declare a file path in java

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app that involves an internal database. I decided to open the database file rather than produce it within the app.

this is the code:

```
private static String databasePath = "H:\Workspace\PetrocVLE\assets";
public SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, 0);
```

this is the error that is being given:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

I thought this might mean that there are symbols within the databasePath variable which are not allowed within a string variable, however I have seen other String variables that used these within java.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? thankyou

Comment: Just [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the backslashes with a backslash: "H:\\W..".

Comment: see also: [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

Comment: Ermm ... why are you using Windows pathname syntax on Android?

Comment: Agree with @StephenC - I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here but I'm pretty sure it wont work.

Comment: Because for now I'm making it on my computer. the file path will be changed once I start using it on the app to an SD card location or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is a special character used in Java `Strings`, you would need to escape it,

```
private static String databasePath = "H:\\Workspace\\PetrocVLE\\assets";
```

However, file paths on Android normally take this format

```
private static String databasePath = "/Workspace/PetrocVLE/assets";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `/` instead, since it's OS-independent:

```
private static String databasePath = "H:/Workspace/PetrocVLE/assets";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to be drive independent and either refer to a variable representing your drive letter or try using [relative paths](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Absolutepathandrelativepath.htm).